# Having trouble setting color in fragment shader

Tags: opengl, glsl, fragment-shader

For some reason, the color isn't applying to the object. Here's my fragment shader code. There's probably something obvious wrong with it that i'm not seeing.

```
#version 330 core
out vec3 Color;

uniform int InColor;

void main()
{
        Color = vec3(float(127 / 255), 0, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value `127 / 255` is an integer division and always has the value zero.

You want `vec3(127.0 / 255.0, 0.0, 0.0)` instead.

Comment: You can't divide integers?

Comment: I mean integers, sorry.

Comment: Glsl integer division will give an integer result. So 127/255 = 0.49 which is rounded to 0.

Comment: You can divide integers, but in GLSL, as is the case in C, C++ and many other languages, the result of `127 / 255` will be `0`.